# Missing comments. Who deleted them?

Tags: discussion

[Ethernet is disabled after reboot - Ubuntu server 20.04.3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1383206/ethernet-is-disabled-after-reboot-ubuntu-server-20-04-3)

Question posted yesterday.

I left a comment requesting more info from the OP. OP responded with info, and then pinged me with a comment to let me know that the requested info had been made available.

This morning my comment requesting more info is missing, and so is the ping comment that OP left for me. **Without the OP's ping comment, how am I supposed to know that the requested info is available?**

Who deleted them? Why?

Comment: you've been here long enough to know that people can downvote for whatever reason and not leave feedback.  The accusatory tone in your post is probably offputting and making people consider this in a negative tone.  Which makes sense for people to just downvote and not comment.

Comment: https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6764/what-do-you-do-about-unexplained-downvotes for your awareness about 'unexplained feedback'

Comment: @heynnema See [this Meta SE answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325416/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin) regarding why people don't have to leave a comment.

Answer (score 6):

This is completely normal. Mods will regularly delete obsolete comments, and a comment asking for more info is a typical example of an obsolete comment (once the info has been added). This is the expected behavior.

As for being notified, there is no mechanism to notify users when their comments are deleted, and cleaning up comments is a major part of the janitorial work moderators do.

I see you re-added the comment but since the OP has already given you the info you needed, I flagged it as obsolete again, so it will soon be removed.

Comment: I've **NEVER** seen this for a request for more info. I've been on AU for 11+ years. The comment also included instruction for how to contact me once the requested info was available. It was posted **YESTERDAY**! And because the comment was deleted, I was never informed by OP that an edit had been made to the question. This must be some new rule?

Comment: You can follow the post to get notified of an update on it. No need to wait for the OP to ping you.

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog For the amount of activity that I do daily, following or bookmarking questions would make my "watch" list very lengthy. I was waiting for OP to ping me to let me know that the data was available.

Comment: @heynnema please don't shout at me. I have no idea why you haven't seen this, it is entirely standard practice across the whole SE network and it is most certainly standard practice here and something I used to do regularly when I was a moderator here.

Comment: I'm not shouting. I've never seen this behavior before. Never. And since my comment contained info for how to contact me, and since the comment was deleted, OP never knew who asked for the info, and how to contact me.

Comment: @heynnema you are still pingable even if your comment is deleted. Since the OP did not actually leave you a comment after editing, I don't see why you think they would do so later. In any case, as I explained, this is the standard operating procedure and has been since the very beginning of the site: comments asking for clarification are deleted once the clarification has been added. (PS for future reference, CAPS and especially **BOLD CAPS** are used to indicate shouting, so please avoid that if you don't actually want to shout).

Comment: How am I still pingable if the only comment that contained my user ID is deleted? I used bold caps for emphasis.

Comment: @heynnema even users who have just edited the post are pingable. I assume it is stored in the DB somehow even if no longer visible (and I know that deleted comments are visible to mods, so they are not completely gone). In any case, whatever the mechanics you are still pingable.

Comment: Please explain how, from an OP's viewpoint, how to ping a person when you don't have their user ID any more.

Comment: @heynnema the OP did not ping you. The comment will have been deleted _after_ the OP had edited, so the OP had already chosen not to ping you and deleting the comment would have made no difference. Of course it is not easy for the OP to ping you without your username, no argument there. In any case, I am just explaining the mechanism. I did not delete the comment, I am not a mod here and I cannot do anything about it. Please take it up with the local mods if you feel that is necessary, just remember that this is and always has been standard practice.

Comment: @heynnema You click *Follow* below the post, right next to *Edit*.

Comment: @terdon Turns out that the OP **did** ping me, but that comment had been deleted also, so I never saw that either.

Comment: @heynnema **this is the typical behavior here on Ask Ubuntu** for comments - after they've served a purpose they get flagged and/or deleted - that's been this way since LONG before even I was a moderator, and has always been how comments behave.  The other times you see comments like this not get deleted are when they get moved to *chat* because y'all overuse comments and don't use the "Take this to chat instead" option it poses you when you use too many comments.  In which case, those comments are erased anyways.

Comment: @ThomasWard re: *"after they've served a purpose they get flagged and/or deleted"*, and when the OP leaves me a ping that says "I've supplied the requested information", and that gets deleted too, you don't see what's wrong with that process... especially since I'm talking about a question asked just **yesterday**? How am I supposed to do this then? I can't just keep checking back in on questions to see if they've been edited, or additional comments made. Please explain it.

Comment: @heynnema it's up to each moderator who handles those flags as to judgement.  Only the mod who did the delete can explain the judgement of them for their removal.  It's also not my position to point fingers, so my suggestion is "go take a break and a walk" and cool off before coming back to have a civil discussion on these things.  Your tone suggests you're angry and aggressive, so go take a walk.

Comment: @ThomasWard I took a walk. Regarding... when the OP leaves me a ping that says *"I've supplied the requested information"*, and that gets deleted too... how am I supposed to know that I can proceed with the review?

Answer (score 6):

That would be me. I flagged those two comments on [that post](https://askubuntu.com/q/1383206/1438484) as "No longer needed". You asked the OP to add some information to the post, which is fine, and what comments are for. The OP then added that information, and commented something like

> @heynnema I added the information

But at that point, once the information was added, the comments were no longer needed, so I flagged them as such. Note that I flagged them *after* the OP added the requested info, so the OP did what was asked, but once that happened, the comments didn't need to stay.

[image: Screenshot of my flags which were marked helpful]

Once the requested information was added by the OP, the comments weren't needed because the OP already did it, and to everyone else, they are just noise. That is why I flagged them.

Comment: Thanks for stepping up. I never saw the *"@heynnema I added the information"* comment, and that was what I was waiting for, a ping, to know that I needed to review their edits. With both of those comments deleted, it's just that I happened by the question this morning, and found the edits quite by accident.

Comment: Yeah... it would be nice (and I would support it on Meta SE, for that matter) if there was a "notify me when this question is edited, but don't for other things" feature. Like, I might want to say "Tell me if this question is commented on or edited, but don't tell me if an answer was posted". I would support that fully. I see why you were annoyed that you weren't told that it was edited, though/

Comment: Update: I found [a Meta SE request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80460/1081494) for one to be notified when a question is deleted, so check that out, it might help you

Comment: If I was a third party reader/viewer, and read those two (deleted) comments, it would give me some history, and I'd also know that those requests for info had already be asked, and that I would not need to re-ask for the same information again. Good audit trail.

Comment: @heynnema I respectfully disagree. To decide if they should ask the OP to add something, they should _simply read the question_ to see if it is already there. They shouldn't have to read the comments.

Comment: Thanks for the dialog, and your time.